# Where are windows's repair tools located?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-8

I am talking about the repair tools that show up at startup if your PC runs into a problem on a windows installation.
I've always been wondering where these programs are located in the file system.
Windows 8 has updated the repair tools's appearance and how they work, are they located in a different place than windows 7's repair tools?
I looked up my question on google but surprisingly I did not find any answer.

Comment: In the Windows RE partition. Usually the first partition on the C drive.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to make it visible in explorer or diskpart ?

Comment: Yes, `list vol` then `sel vol number` where number is the volume number of the `C:` drive and `list part` and Recovery should be there

Comment: or use disk management and assign a drive letter, then you can see contents in explorer./